# Using R to read all files in a specific format and with specific extension

Tags: r, regex

I want to read all the files in the xlsx format starting with a string named "csmom". I have used list.files function. But I do not know how to set double pattern. Please see the code. I want to read all the files starting csmom string and they all should be in .xlsx format.

```
master1<-list.files(path = "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/csmomentum funal",pattern="^csmom")
master2<-list.files(path = "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/csmomentum funal",pattern="^\\.xlsx$")
```

Comment: Just a side question: _How_ do you plan to read those Excel files in R?  Keep in mind that Excel's file format is _binary_, meaning you can't just read it using something like `read.csv`, because you will just get a bunch of binary.

Comment: Try `"^clsmom.*?.*\\.xlsx$"`.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen , Sir I will read them with the help of do.call, lapply and read_excel functions. Because I want to combine every first column of every file. For example do.call(cbind, lapply(masterlist, function(x) read_excel(file=x)[, 1])).

Comment: @jay.sf Thanks sir it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jay.sf solution works for creating a regular expression to pull out the condition that you want.

However, generally speaking if you want to cross two lists to find the subset of elements that are contained in both (in your case the files that satisfy both conditions), you can use `intersect()`.

```
intersect(master1, master2)
```

Will show you all the files that satisfy pattern 1 and pattern 2.